# Duals of Sobolev Spaces vanishing on parts of the boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace, finite-element-method

I am revising for a Finite Elements course and have the following question about the definition of $H^{-1}$.

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be bounded Lipschitz domain and let $\Gamma_0 \subseteq \partial D$ be a part of positive measure of the boundary where we put Dirichlet conditions.

We define $V_0:=\{v \in H^1(D) : v|_{\Gamma_0} \equiv 0\}$ and $H_0^1(D):=\{v \in H^1(D) : v|_{\partial D}\equiv 0\}$.

Taking duals obviously yields $(V_0)^\ast \hookrightarrow (H_0^1(D))^\ast$.

My question: How can I construct an example of a function in $H_0^1(D)^\ast$ that does not lie in $V_0^\ast$?

Comment: Taking duals should be the other way around.

Comment: Since $H^1_0 \subset V_0$, $(V_0)^* \subset (H^1_0)^*$ (you can "do more" to a function which vanishes on more of the boundary).

Comment: The inclusion of the dual spaces goes the other way around: $H^1_0 \subset V_0$, hence a linear and continuous map on $V_0$ is linear and continuous on $H^1_0$.

Comment: Corrected it, sorry and thanks for pointing out. But still, how to construct an example?

Comment: Perhaps $F(f)=\int_{\partial D} ((Tr(f))(x))^4 dS(x)$? (Here $Tr$ denotes the trace.) This is just zero on $H^1_0$ but it is not even finite for some members of $V_0$. You could probably adjust this to get something defined on $V_0$ but not bounded.

Comment: @Ian: that is a very good idea! isn't it enough to consider a non linear $g$ to get the result?

Comment: @Giovanni Well no; for instance, the trace theorem says that we can't just square the trace and integrate. (In fact, the "strong" trace theorem would tell us that the trace of an $H^1$ function is $H^{1/2}$ on the boundary, which is better than just $L^2$.) But the trace will still map to some functions with "limited" integrability (i.e. they are not in every $L^p$ for all $p<\infty$), and this is exploiting that.

Comment: @Giovanni Oh, now I see what you meant, you're right, anything nonlinear will work, since such a functional could never be linear on $V_0$, so it couldn't be in the dual of $V_0$ (even the algebraic one).

Comment: @Ian: I am sorry but I am not sure that this is what I was asking, I'll try to explain a little bit better. I was referring to your comment before the edit, in which you consider $\int g(Tr(f))$ with $g(0) = 0$. This gives a linear and continuous functional on $H^1_0$, but perhaps we can choose a non linear $g$ so that we don't get $T(f + h) = T(f) + T(h)$ for functions with non zero trace. EDIT: I have just read your comment, we posted at the same time. I am glad we are on the same page, thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counterexample could be intuitively constructed exploiting the fact that any singular part of the functional on boundary will get killed by the $H^1_0(D)$.

The simplest possible example is: choose a singular $g\in H^{-1/2-\epsilon}(\partial D)$ for some $\epsilon >0$
$$
\mathcal{L}(v) := \int_{\partial D} g \cdot \operatorname{tr}(v) dS
$$
(omitting the independent variable here).

We can check that $\mathcal{L}(\cdot)$ vanishes for any $v\in H^1_0(D)$, but we can choose certain $g$ that $\mathcal{L}(\cdot)$ is not bounded for all $v\in V_0$, because the singularites do not get killed on the other part of the boundary except the Dirichlet part.

And this is part of the reason we need Neumann data in at least $H^{-1/2}(\Gamma_N)$ where $\Gamma_N$ is the Neumann boundary, if I assume we are interested in the weak formulation in the Hilbertian setting. If $g \in H^{-1/2}(\partial D)$ above, above functional will be bounded for any $H^1(D)$ which can be proved by trace inequality.

---

A concrete example of above functional: let $D= (0,1)^2$, let $\Gamma_0$ be the top three sides' union, the rest of the boundary, which lies on the $x$-axis, is say $\Gamma_N$, then the singular functional is
$$\mathcal{L}(v):=\int_{[0,1]\times \{0\}} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}\ln x} v|_{y=0}\, dx, \quad \text{where } \alpha>1.
$$
On the boundary where $y=0$, we can simply let the trace of $v$ be $x$ from $[0,1/2]$, $1-x$ from $[1/2, 1]$, and $0$ on all three other sides, and this trace is continuous on $\partial D$ so it can be extended continuously inside as an $E(v) \in H^1(D)$ function. It can be checked that the integral diverges for this $E(v) \in H^1(D)$.